# I am having trouble writing the code correctly php

Tags: php, wordpress, for-loop, variables, foreach

I need to help in a small problem , but for me it is big and I haven't found a solution since yesterday

This code works fine for me, but it is displayed to $ watch_server_rows [2] but it does not display to me $ watch_server_rows [1] because writing the code contains an error. I don’t know where it is in

; Or "

Also please do not check in my English and thanks haha

```
$newURL =site_url(). "/wp-content/apps/embed.php?v=custom&s=". $watch_server_rows[2];"&set=". $watch_server_rows[1];
```

Comment: Is there an error displayed or does something not work?  What does `$newURL` contain after this line.

Comment: @NigelRen An error code does not appear, but this code does not work or appears; "& set =". $ watch_server_rows [1];

Comment: @user4158643 hello, it's seems that you have a typo with  `;` after ` $watch_server_rows[2]`. If you want to contact string you need to use `.`